# Move files to directories depending on their extension

Tags: scripts

I have a directory with huge number of files with different extensions. What I want to do is to move each extension to a folder with name the extension itself, and those files without extension move to a folder named `unkown`.

For example I have the files `a.txt`, `b.txt` ,`a.pdf`, `b.pdf` , `a.mp4` , `file`, `newfile` ....

The result would be 4 dirs named `txt`, `pdf`, `mp4` , `unkonw`

the `txt` dir contains the files `a.txt`, `b.txt`

the `pdf` dir contains the files `a.pdf`, `b.pdf`

the `mp4` dir contains the files `a.mp4`

the `unkonw` dir contains the files `file`, `newfile`

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your question. you mean to move `a.txt` and  `b.txt` to the `txt` directory and `file` and `newfile` to the `unknown` directory. Also I want to ask are there only these four extensions or are there many more?

Comment: yeah sorry typo error

Comment: No there is much more this is just an example

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way:

```
mkdir -p unknown; 
for f in *; do 
[[ $f =~ \. ]] && mkdir -p "${f##*.}" && 
               mv "$f" "${f##*.}"/ || 
mv "$f" unknown/; done
```

#### Explanation

- `&&` means "run the command on the right only if the command on the left was successful".
- `||` means "run the command on the right only if the command on the left failed". The two symbols combined can work like an `if/else` block.
- `mkdir -p unknown;` : create the `unknown` directory. The `-p` is there so that `mkdir` won't complain if the directory exists.
- `for f in *` : for all files and directories in the current directory.
- `[[ $f =~ \. ]] &&` : if the current file/dir name contains a `.`, if it has an extension, then...
- `mkdir -p "${f##*.}"/` : the construct `${var##pat}` will remove the longest match of `pat` from the beginning of variable `$var`. Here, the `pat` is anything up to a dot, so this will leave only the extension. This command, therefore, creates the extension's directory if it doesn't exist.
- `mv "$f" "${f##*.}"/` : The `mv` then moves the file into the relevant directory.
  `|| mv "$f" unknown/;` : if the previous command failed (if this file/directory) does not have an extension, move it to `unknown`.

Note that this will print this error message, but you can safely ignore it:

```
mv: cannot move ‘unknown’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘unknown/unknown’
```

If you need to move only files and no directories (the commands above will also move a directory called `dir.foo` into `foo/`), use this instead:

```
mkdir -p unknown; 
for f in *; do 
[[ -f $f ]] && 
    if [[ $f =~ \. ]]; then 
        mkdir -p "${f##*.}" && 
        mv "$f" "${f##*.}"/; 
    else mv "$f" unknown/; fi; 
done
```

Answer (score 4):

This `bash` script will do that: run it with `bash script.sh <path>` or `./script.sh <path>`, where `<path>` is the path to the folder containing the files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for path in ${1}/*
do
    if [ -f "${path}" ]
    then
        extension="$(<<< "${file}" sed -rn 's/^.*\.(.*)$/\1/p')"
        if [ -n "${extension}" ]
        then
            mkdir -p "${1}/${extension}"
            mv "${path}" "${1}/${extension}"
        else
            mkdir -p "${1}/unknown"
            mv "${path}" "${1}/unknown"
        fi
    fi
done
```

`tree` output before and after running the script on a `tmp` directory:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tree tmp
tmp
├── a.mp4
├── a.pdf
├── a.txt
├── b.pdf
├── b.txt
├── file
├── folder
└── newfile

1 directory, 7 files
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ bash script tmp/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tree tmp
tmp
├── folder
├── mp4
│   └── a.mp4
├── pdf
│   ├── a.pdf
│   └── b.pdf
├── txt
│   ├── a.txt
│   └── b.txt
└── unknown
    ├── file
    └── newfile

5 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: Is it a simpler method to get the extension?

Comment: @Maythux I'm no `bash` parameter expansion expert, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) answer, `filename="$(basename "$file")"; extension="${filename##*.}"` will do

Comment: easily you can replace your extension line with this     `extension="${file##*.}"`

Comment: Also still some weakness in your script, it will move folders also not only files, so you have to check if it is a file, please fix it to mark it again as answer

Comment: @Maythux I updated to exclude folders, however I'm having some troubles using the parameter expansion suggested in that answer. I'm unable to test further as of now, I'll update later and drop you a comment once done